# Where to find all Flutter SocketException: OS ErrorCodes

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, socketexception

Where can I find all Http OS Error codes for a `SocketException`. When I make a request there is a chance that it will throw a `SocketException` with an `OSError` containing an error code and a message. Where can I find all possible error codes so I can handle them accordingly?

```dart
try {
      final response = await postRequest(
  ApiUtil.getGetApisUrl,
  headers: {
    "P_USER_NAME": userId!,
    "P_TYPE": 1.toString(), // 1: Employee, 2: Student
    "AUTH": _dbUserAuthToken!,
    "P_Lang": 2.toString(),
  },
);

} on SocketException catch (e) {
  debugPrint(e.toString());
  // WHERE CAN I FIND ALL ERROR CODES SO I CAN HANDLE IT HERE
  if (e.osError?.errorCode == 8) { // ErrorCode 8 is for example "Failed host lookup"
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
        MyApp.globalNavigatorKey.currentContext!, Routes.maintenanceScreen);
  } else {
    Navigator.pushNamed(
        MyApp.globalNavigatorKey.currentContext!, Routes.noInternet);
  }
} catch (e) {
  debugPrint(e.toString());
}
```

Comment: That would be in the OS´s documentation

Comment: I have not found anything @Ber Maybe you find

Comment: I do not know where you got you error code 8 from. Here is a list of common error numbers: https://gist.github.com/gabrielfalcao/4216897

Comment: @Ber I got an error then I checked the Errorcode inside the exception which was 8 and it's message was "Failed host lookup"